# Are discussing features broadly and discussing this feature specific to a language considered duplicates?

Tags: discussion

- A: [What are the advantages and disadvantages of the callee versus caller clearing the stack after a call?](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/2220/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-the-callee-versus-caller-clearing-t)
- B: [Why was C implemented with a register preservation convention that seems to be far less efficient than its predecessor's?](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/618/why-was-c-implemented-with-a-register-preservation-convention-that-seems-to-be-f)

I think A & B are essentially the same question, A is about this feature, and B is specific to the trade-off of this feature in the C language.

But sometimes B also makes sense, and if a language is completely different from other mainstream implementations, does it have its own considerations, which is worth asking?

Judging from the timeline, A is duplicated, but A is obviously not suitable for merging into B.

(I think A is indeed duplicated, but it is even more strange to merge A into B, so I did not vote Close)

Comment: "*B is specific to the trade-off of this feature in the C language*". Not necessarily. For instance it's possible that when C was written, the target architecture already had established libraries that used the other convention, so "when in Rome" was the deciding factor rather than anything specific to the actual choices. If that were the case, neither question would provide a suitable answer for the other. ¶ (In retrospect, question B might have been a better fit for the Retro Computing site.)

Comment: Be aware that [chronology is not a factor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251938) in choosing duplicates ([also](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423085); [also](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424208)) on Stack Overflow, and in principle the same applies across the network ([original guidance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see these as separate questions. `question_A` is about generalized decision making. `question_B` is about an already-made design choice in a specific language, which has a design committee, steering goals, and a long history including technology ecosystem history- that's a very specific context.

I suppose there could be an argument for answering `question_A` based on an answer to `question_B` by using C as a case study, which has its usefulness... But the questions are still not the same. See also [How does duplicate closing work? When is a question a duplicate, and how should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841/997587)

Answer (score 1):

## Yes, but merge the other way round

An answer to B is a completely reasonable answer to A. The reverse is not true (an answer to A which discusses JVM calling conventions is not really appropriate on B, as phrased). So I would advocate for dupe-hammering B to link to A and leaving A open.

Timeline is only one factor to consider when deciding which way to dupe-hammer. Yes, B is older. But B is also more specific. Both have good answers, and A has more upvotes. I don't think it's a problem to consider the newer question as the canonical one in this case.